# ReactJS search page set/get query string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a search page in my react app, I want to when user add a filter, set a parameter to url, and also when refresh page with those query string, get data from API. What I tried so far:

```
getProvince = (e, {value}) => {
  this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/Search',
      search: '?Province=' + value
  })
}

getCity = (e, {value}) => {
  this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/Search',
      search: '?City=' + value
  })
}
```

**But the problems are:**

1. It just add province, or city, not together, I need to append query string not replace. goal: /Search?Province=1&City=2
2. How can I remove query string when user remove that filter?
3. How can I get data from API based on what on query string?

This function get data from API:

```
getUpdate = async () => {
    let data = {
        province: this.state.provinceValue,
        city: this.state.cityValue,
        district: this.state.districtValue
    }

    const result = await API.getSearch(data);

    if(result.status === 200){
        this.setState({data: result})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getProvince = (e, {value}) => {
  this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/Search',
      search: '?Province=' + value
  })
}

getCity = (e, {value}) => {
  this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/Search',
      search: '?City=' + value
  })
}
```

1. It just add province, or city, not together, I need to append query
   string not replace. goal: /Search?Province=1&City=2

   You could combine the 2 functions into one:

   ```
   getCityProvince = (city, province) => {
      var search_query = "";
      if(city.length > 0) {
         search_query+= "?City=" + city
      }
      if((province.length > 0) && (search_query === "")) {
         search_query+= "?Province=" + province
      } else {
         search_query+= "&Province=" + province
      }   
      this.props.history.push({
          pathname: '/Search',
          search: search_query
       })
   }
   ```
2. How can I remove query string when user remove that filter?

   If user removes a query you need to combine it maybe with a state?
   Then that function just calls `getCityProvince(city, province)` if
   city or province is empty it will only search the other, so the
   empty one will be removed.

   Here you could use:

   ```
   componentDidMount() {}

   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {}
   ```
3. How can I get data from API based on what on query string?

   ```
   getUpdate = async () => {
       let data = {
           province: this.state.provinceValue,
           city: this.state.cityValue,
           district: this.state.districtValue
       }

       const result = await API.getSearch(data);

       if(result.status === 200){
           this.setState({data: result})
       }
   }
   ```

   In getUpdate you can use:

   ```
   let Province = this.props.match.params.Province;
   let City = this.props.match.params.City;
   ```

   that will get the value from the params in the URL.

Good luck, hope this helps! :)

Comment: Haven't tested the code, if there is any syntax mistakes it was by accident. Please let me know if you have issues, I'm sure we can solve any! :)